# Collect OpenTelemetry Logs from stdout into fluentbit

Tags: open-telemetry, fluent-bit, open-telemetry-collector

My application uses OpenTelemetry format to create logs in Opentelemetry and send to STDout/console in Kubernetes. I would like to "collect" that logs with fluentbit and send it to an DB.

The "Inputs" -> "OpenTelemetry" from Fluentbit gives the following options. Which doesn't include the option to read them from SDTOut.

`The OpenTelemetry plugin allows you to ingest telemetry data as per the OTLP specification, from various **OpenTelemetry exporters**, the **OpenTelemetry Collector**, or **Fluent Bit's OpenTelemetry output plugin**.`

Can one of you let me know how I would import the stdout data in opentelemetry format? Do I need to add opentelemetry Collector first?

I tried to read the logs into fluentbit. It reads every line (Inputs->tail) and exports it seperately. I expected that the Fluentbit can read and interpret the OpenTelemetry data from STDOut of my application and send it to some DB.

Comment: What language is your application written in? Instructions to set up exporting logs are different for different languages.

Comment: I am using different languages in a microservice architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send the logs from your application using an OTLP exporter rather then sending them to console/stdout. Standard output is supposed to be used for debugging purposes. Follow documentation specific to your application's language for details. Note that you might need to configure the OTLP exporter to use HTTP and not gRPC as the transport protocol.

For example, if your application was written in .NET, you would use the `AddOtlpExporter` helper function with the `Protocol` set to `OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf`, as described here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/core-1.7.0/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol/README.md#enable-log-exporter.

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed that it would be possible to collect the logs from stdout but from documentation it seems that i have to use the http or gRPC instead. 
I accept as an answer